# cannot get a response from NodeJS server using remote method in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, jquery-validate

I'm working on a signup page. I want to validate the input email using jQuery Validation. The server is written in NodeJS (with ExpressJS). As I tab out of the email input, it should send me a message that the email has already existed. Instead, it gives me an error of GET http://0.0.0.0:3000/checkemail?... 404 Not Found in the console.

```
signup.js (linked to the frontend signup form)

   $('#register-form').validate({
       rules: {
           email: {
               required: true,
               email: true,
               remote: 'http://0.0.0.0:3000/checkemail'
           }
       }
   });

app.js (server-side in NodeJS)

   app.get('/checkemail', function(req, res){
        var params = req.url.split('?')[1];
        var data = querystring.parse(params);
        var email = data.email;

        if(emailExists(email)){ //if email already exists, write false
            res.write('""');
        } else {
            res.write('"true"');
        }
    });
```

Comment: First off, why are you doing this: `var params = req.url.split('?')[1];`?

Try doing `req.query.email` instead,  as seen in the docs [here](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.query).

Once you've done that, try and do a console.log of email before your if statement and validate that the data has made it there.

Comment: @JacobW I tried yours but it doesn't seem to work. I think the problem here is that the frontend couldn't get its request to the server because:
1. the error message is GET http://0.0.0.0:3000/checkemail?email=[email] 404 (Not Found)
2. there is no email being logged out in the server console even tho I added console.log(email) after I assigned var email = req.query.email

Comment: The `remote` method needs a JSON encoded response from the server.  Also, if you're getting a 404 on your URL, then I doubt it has anything to do with `remote` or any of this code.  Figure out why the URL cannot be found!

Comment: @Sparky yeah. Other app.get() and app.post() on the serverside work perfectly except for app.get(‘/checkemail’) and I don’t know why til now